# How to loop through filtered list

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, filter, range

I'm currently stuck with my codes on looping through a filtered list, select and copy certain cells from the rows and paste it to another sheet.

My codes looks like this :

```
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iRow2 As Integer

LastCol = Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
For iRow = 2 To wb1.Sheets("1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For iRow2 = 6 To wb1.Sheets("n").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If wb1.Sheets("n").Cells(iRow2, d8).Value > End_Date Then
        If wb1.Sheets("n").Cells(iRow2, LastCol).Value <> "x" Then
            wb1.Sheets("n").Range("Cells(iRow2, d1), Cells(iRow2, d2), Cells(iRow2, d3), Cells(iRow2, d4), Cells(iRow2, d5), Cells(iRow2, d6), Cells(iRow2, d7)").Select
            wb1.Sheets("n").Range(Cells(iRow2, d7)).Activate
            Selection.Copy
            wb1.Activate
            wb1.Sheets("1").Cells(iRow, d21).PasteSpecial
            wb1.Sheets("n").Cells(iRow2, LastCol).Value = "x"
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next iRow2
Next iRow
```

The End_
Date value varies as it's entered by user.

Comment: Can you detail a bit more what you are trying to achieve? Because if your first loop only purpose is to increment the rows that you are pasting on, it isn't the right way to do it. You should use `wb1.Sheets("1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1` each time before pasting.

Comment: @R3uK Oh yeah thanks for editing that part! I reused the previous codes I had and did not notice the mistake! But yeah I'll need to loop through the filtered list in sheet("n") and if the date in column d8 is later than End_Date, I'll copy d1 to d7(not in continuous range) from the same row and paste it to sheet("1").

Answer (score 0):

Note that you'll have to recalculate `PasteRow` in each loop to be able to know where you are supposed to paste.

After clarification, here is your code :

```
Sub test_Smer()

Dim LastCol As Long, _
    wsN As Worksheet, _
    ws1 As Worksheet, _
    LastRow As Long, _
    PasteRow As Long, _
    iRow As Long, _
    CopyRange As String

Set wsN = wb1.Sheets("n")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("1")
LastCol = wsN.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
LastRow = wsN.Cells(wsN.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With wsN
    For iRow = 6 To LastRow
        If .Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        Else
            If .Cells(iRow, d8).Value > end_date Then
                If wsN.Cells(iRow, LastCol).Value <> "x" Then
                    CopyRange = Replace(.Cells(iRow, d1).Address & "," & _
                        .Cells(iRow, d2).Address & "," & _
                        .Cells(iRow, d3).Address & "," & _
                        .Cells(iRow, d4).Address & "," & _
                        .Cells(iRow, d5).Address & "," & _
                        .Cells(iRow, d6).Address & "," & _
                        .Cells(iRow, d7).Address, "$", "")
                    .Range(CopyRange).Copy

                    PasteRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    ws1.Cells(PasteRow, d21).PasteSpecial

                    .Cells(iRow, LastCol).Value = "x"
                    Exit For
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if this does the trick but it seems like its looping through the whole list. I'm looking to loop through a filtered list(only visible cells). Really sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help man! My codes managed to work! :)

Comment: Glad I could help! If an answer solved your problem, please accept it to mark your question as resolved (click on the tick just under the up/down vote). And when any post seems useful or of good quality to you, you can (after earning 15 reputation) up vote it! Welcome to SO and enjoy! ;)